# Best DPI for iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, image

If an image has a display size of 200 x 300 in an app (using the local coordinate system) I currently supply an image of size 600 x 900 at 72 DPI (3 times bigger), and the device shrinks it down so it displays crisply for retina displays. I was curious as to whether other developers prefer to increase the DPI, say to 300 but reduce the total width x height, and if so, if they have seen any size benefits (with knock-on effects for download times etc.)

Comment: This question might be a better fit for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Good idea would probably be to follow [iOS guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/), by providing different assets from @1x to @3x, depending on target device:

> **Supply high-resolution images for all artwork in your app, for all
> devices your app supports.** Depending on the device, you accomplish
> this by multiplying the number of pixels in each image by a specific
> scale factor.

Comment: For locally stored artwork that’s fine, but in reality pretty much all devices are retina now anyway so using 3 times bigger allows the device to scale down for (rare) cases where 1x and 2x are needed. I’m thinking particularly of download times vs crispness.